# Handling Currency for different locales in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, locale

I have a use case of adding or deleting certain items in a widget and correspondingly adding or subtracting prices in the total amount.
But while trying to handle this addition/subtraction in javascript i am facing issues for e.g
if the price is in the form of 1,50,000 or its like 1.50,000 (europe regions which treat comma as decimal).
So is there a way that i can generically handle these? Any service or libraries?

Comment: Have you looked on NPM for packages? https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=money or   https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=currency

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Comment: A simple solution, if you can guarantee that your prices will be whole numbers, is to simply strip all non-numeric characters from the input. (Also, don't use "1,50,000" as a generic display format for internationalization! That way of grouping digits is completely unheard of outside of India.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript's Internationalisation function - `Intl.NumberFormat()` to which you can pass `locale` and `currency` to format the number.

Find more information here -

https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

Comment: That doesn't help with "*is there a way that i can generically handle these*", the issue being how does the OP determine the language to pass to the Intl formatter (noting that *navigator.language* is unreliable)?